# Find the explicit form of the polar cone

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In this question, we need to find the explicit form of the polar $C^*$ of the cone $$C=\lbrace (x_1,x_2):x_2\geq-3|x_1|\rbrace. $$
I know we need to find $ C^*=\{p:p^tx\le 0,\forall x\in C\}$ as the polar cone, but I have troubles of finding $C^*$, could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: Yes, it is two lines with slope -3 starting at (0,0) and ending at the negative infinity.@user251257

Comment: in that picture can you draw any line going through zero such that $C$ is completely on one side of that line?

Comment: No. @user251257

Comment: So what the polar cone?